# Problem with proving simple martingale property

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, martingales, expected-value

I want to prove the following property :

Let $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ be a martingale with respect to the filtration $(F_n)$.

Let's also assume that $E(X_n^2),E(Y_n^2)<+\infty$

Prove that $$E(X_{n-1}Y_{n-1})=\frac{E(X_nY_{n-1})+E(X_{n-1}Y_n)}{2}$$

Above fact is obvious when $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ are independent due to fact that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are marginals with respect to the filtration $(F_n)$

(Then $E(X_n)=E(X_{n-1}$),$E(Y_n)=E(Y_{n-1}),E(X_nY_n)=E(X_n)E(Y_n),E(X_{n-1}Y_{n-1})=E(X_{n-1})E(Y_{n-1}))$.

But I don't have idea in a general case when $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are not independent. I tried to use some martingales properties but i didnt't get anything crucial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$ X_{n-1} Y_{n-1} = (X_{n-1} - X_n) Y_{n-1} + X_n Y_{n-1} $$
and 
$$X_{n-1} Y_{n-1} = X_{n-1} (Y_{n-1} - Y_n) + X_{n-1} Y_n. $$
For the right-hand side of the first equation we can use
\begin{align*}
E[(X_{n-1} - X_n) Y_{n-1}] &= E[E[(X_{n-1} - X_n) Y_{n-1}| F_{n-1}]] \\
&= E[Y_{n-1}\ E[(X_{n-1} - X_n) | F_{n-1}]] \\
&= 0,
\end{align*}
where the last equality follows by the martingale property for $\{X_n\}$. We can do the same for the second equation using the martingale property of $\{Y_n\}$. Adding the equations together, taking expectations, and dividing by 2 yields the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer!

Comment: I have just one question about the very last equality. 
$E[(X_{n-1}-X_n)|F_{n-1})=X_{n-1}-E(X_n)$.

Comment: The first component of the sum is because of measurable and the second one because of independence. 
I don't see why it's equal to $0$ if I am correctly

Comment: $E[X_n | F_{n-1}] = X_{n-1}$ from the martingale property.

Comment: what a shame! Thank you very much for your patience and help!

Comment: I get it now of course